# How to count the number of lines in the region?

Tags: region, lines

Is there a command similar to `count-words-region` to count the total number of lines of a selected region?

Comment: "The `count-words-region` command, when called interactively, reports the number of lines, words, and characters in the region.  It is a superset of the old `count-lines-region`, which is now an obsolete alias for it." -- NEWS.24

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`M-=` (command `count-words-region`).

(The region does not even need to be activated, but activating it lets you see it.)

Comment: How do you get the number of lines from this command? It's displayed but how do you get it in a variable?

Comment: some good examples in: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WordCount

Answer (score 5):

Count lines does the trick, it is defined in simple.el

```
(count-lines (point-min) (point-max))
```